# jquery modal opens to full page

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a nested jquery modals Modal1 & modal2 both contain updatePanels. To update the panels I am using javascript:

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm._doPostBack('UpDateLookUp','');
```

UpDateLookUp is the id of the updatePanel for modal1. Modal1 contains the link, which is in the updatePanel, for modal2. Modal1 updatePanel is a search criteria(Find) outside of the panel which works great while I am on modal1 but when I open modal2 (has an wpdatePaneltoo) and I go back to modal1, select Find modal2 opens to full page and displays the info before it was closed & returned to modal1. If I click on the link that opened modal2 all is well it only occurs when I select a different button.

I am new to jquery so please help. this is the way our shop is going.

Comment: im sorry but this isnt making much sense.  Please try rephrasing the problem better.  Also, try showing more code.  Is this asp.net stuff?

Comment: This is about models, right? "Modal" has a completely different meaning.

Answer (score 0):

There are two or three things you'll want here.  First of all, if whatever control you're hooking on is disappearing in your ajax post-back you'll want to re-hook your event handlers when the page reloads using the following:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) 
{
    if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) 
    {
        //Re-hook code here
    }
}
```

or use the .live() function in the $(document).ready() function to add your event hooks.  This function is well documented on [JQuery UI's API site](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Also, if you want an animation effect to hide something before doing the post-back (which will keep it from changing before the animation is complete) use the .Promise().Done() functions like so:

```
$("#Detail").fadeOut().promise().done(function () 
{
    __doPostBack('<%= UpdatePanel1.ClientID %>', '');
});
```

Lastly, when you want an animation to happen when a post-back is complete to show its results, you can use all this in combination with a boolean variable that enables an action in the pageLoad function like so:

```
var ShowDetailsOnLoad = false;

function pageLoad(sender, args) 
{
    if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) 
    {
        if (ShowDetailsOnLoad)
        {
            $("#Detail").fadeIn();
            ShowDetailsOnLoad = false;
        }

        $('DetailVisMaker').click(function() 
        {
            $("#Detail").fadeOut().promise().done(function () 
            {
                __doPostBack('<%= UpdatePanel1.ClientID %>', '');
                ShowDetailsOnLoad = true;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

If the divs, HTML, & UpdatePanel are set up correctly, this code will show a detail div, and when the user clicks a link within it, it will fade the detail section out, run a post-back, then fade back in when the post-back is complete.